# [: expr: unexpected operator

Tags: shell-script

I'm learning shell scripting following along an Edureka video and I'm encountering a problem.

I ran this simple script the instructor did first time and everything ran fine but now I can't get it to run.

```
#!/bin/sh

a=0

while [ $a -lt 10 ]
do
        echo $a
        a=' expr $a + 1'
done
```

It's really weird.  It ran first time but since then I get two errors either there's an unexpected operator or there's too many arguments.  I have tried re writing the whole thing from scratch 4 times and it;s the same minus the working first time part.

I read online that it might be to do with the syntax of sh vs bash but changing the shebang to bash and executing with bash didn't change.

does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

running on KDE Neon btw

P.S now looks like this

```
#!/bin/sh

a=0
while [ $a -lt 10 ]
do
   echo $a
   a=`expr $a + 1`
done
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show how you're running it and exactly what the error message is that you receive

Comment: Did you create the file on Windows and then copy it to your UNIX/Linux platform, or is the entire exercise on UNIX/Linux?

Comment: @roaima I wrote it in Linux directly from the example given

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with the line

```
a=' expr $a + 1'
```

It should read

```
a=`expr $a + 1`
```

In particular note the backtick characters.  That tells the shell to run the command and set the variable to the output.

The reason the error message appears in the `[` line is because *second* time around the loop, `$a` is the literal string  `expr $a + 1` because of your mistake and that isn't a valid expression.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks man I should be wearing my glasses!

Comment: So I re wrote the script with the backticks this time but now i'm getting  "./while: line 6: [0: command not found"  this message in the terminal

Comment: This time you missed the space after the `[` character.

Comment: There are few cases were you cannot use `$()` instead of backticks; it is definitely preferred because it is (a) more obvious and (b) can be nested.